# Find Metadata using APEX

Tags: apex, metadata

How can I create a VF Page/Lightning Components which shows the list of all the metadata which is created or modified in some specific date range?

To elaborate more let's say I have one VF Page in which I have Two Date Picker Start Date and End Date, after selecting both the date when I click on Submit it should display a list of metadata components (Like ApexClass, CustomFields, Labels) which is created/modified between the specified date range

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query almost everything you want using Tooling API,

Apex Class:

```
SELECT CreatedDate,Id,LastModifiedDate,Name FROM ApexClass
```

Custom Label:

```
SELECT Name,createdDate,LastModifiedDate FROM CustomLabel
```

Custom Field :

```
SELECT Developername,createdDate,LastModifiedDate FROM CustomField
```

Custom Object :

```
 SELECT Developername,createdDate,LastModifiedDate FROM CustomObject
```

[image]

More Objects and references:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcomponent.htm

Comment: Hi, @Pranay, So I need to do a query on every aspect? I mean to say Classes, Objects, Fields etc. Is there any way to get all the data in a single query or without SOQL or can we use Schema class (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm)

Comment: I genuinely doubt there is. Tooling API was designed to build IDE's, Any other API wont provide things that Tooling API provides